# How to fetch Data before Render ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

so I have this custom hook which returns an array of Objects from database, before it gets data, the value of returned value is undefined. `getDataByID(100).doc?.items` - This returns the items from database as an array. How can I make sure that the returned Value is not undefined and then mount the component in functional components?

Comment: In terms of UX, you shouldn't delay the mounting/rendering of components until async stuff like data fetching has completed. Cos if it's slow, they'd see literally nothing while it was loading. Best approach is to handle the loading state with a message or spinner or the like, then re-render with the data once it's fetched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to fetch this data in parent component, and when you received the data then only mount required component as child component and pass those data as props.

```js
{
    (dataFromAPI !== undefined) ? <ChildComponent data={dataFromAPI} /> : undefined
}
```

In this way when you have `dataFromAPI` then only your child component will be mounted.

Comment: This is an example of Conditional Rendering. More information can be found [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Answer (score 0):

Mujibur Rehman Ansari's answer can furthur modified as

```
{ dataFromAPI && <ChildComponent data={dataFromAPI} /> }
```